# Supported music files by BASS audio library

Tags: bass, bass.dll

Is there any way to know if a file extension is supported by Bass audio library (such as WAV/AIFF/MP3/MP2/MP1/OGG )? I would like to write a function like :

```
Public void  Play(string File)
{
   if(IsSupportedFile(file)
     {

       // Add the appropriate code to play the file
     }

}
Public bool isSupported(string File)
{
  // Should return true if the file extension is supported by bass audio and add ons
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
Public bool isSupported(string File)
{
  return Un4seen.Bass.Utils.BASSAddOnIsFileSupported(Nothing, file);
}
```